# Joining two tables having duplicate data in both columns on the base of which we are joining

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. A column named CardName is in first table. There is duplicate data in this columns. That column also exists in second table. There is a column named amount related to each cardName also in second table. What i want is to select distinct CardName from 1st table and and take sum of all the amounts from second column whose cardname is in first table. BUT first table cardname should be distinct.
what should i do?

Comment: yup i got it. will need your help in future too , SIR :)

Comment: do not use SIR. We are all here to help you happily :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name,sum(amount) from tableB 
where name in (select distinct name from TableA) 
group by name
```

use distinct keyword. Distinct will give you only the unique name from TableA and from the sub query result we are getting name and sum from tableB

Refer this : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831(v=sql.105).aspx

From you comment below **UPDATE**

```
with cte (name) as 
(
select distict name from TableA 

)
select cte.name,ISNULL(sum(count),0) from TableB as B 
left join cte.name = B.name
```

Comment: There are some records in Table B which do not exist in table A. We have to select records from A which are distinct and then match it with table B.

Comment: I used your query.  But by using it, i get 102 records. In fact, there are 109 distinct records in Table A.\

Comment: Can you plz explain  more?

Comment: Yes, That is an expected result right? If the name is not in TableA then how can you get the sum. Do you want to display those values with sum = 0 ?

Comment: we have to select distinct records from Table A because there are duplicated data in Table A. Then by taking distinct Cardname from table A, We go to Table B and take sum of Doctotal of those records which are in Table A and are distinct. There are some record in table B which are not in A. For those records, we have to show the sum as null

Comment: For those records of table A, whose doctotal are not in Table B, we have to show them as zero

Comment: Try this Update and let me know